# org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Unknown column 'PrefId' in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, sql-order-by

I am trying to perform a weighted sort on one of the columns (`PrefId`) of my view. I came across `Order By FIELD` for that.

This is my exact query:

```sql
select
  e.employeeName as empName,
  e.employeeLogin as empAlias, 
  e.managerName as mangerName,
  e.managerLogin as managerAlias,
  b.buildingName as buildingName,
  b.country as country,
  b.region as region, 
  CASE WHEN w.preferenceId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE w.preferenceId END as PrefId, 
  CASE WHEN w.lastUpdatedDate IS NULL THEN e.lastUpdatedDate ELSE w.lastUpdatedDate END as updateDate 
FROM employee_details e
INNER JOIN buildings_details as b ON e.building = b.building
LEFT JOIN workplace_details w ON e.employeeId = w.employeeId 
WHERE e.isWorkplacePrefScopeIncluded = 1
ORDER BY FIELD(PrefId, 4, 3, 99, 2, 1, 0);
```

The query works fine on my workbench and the result is as expected but upon executing the same through hibernate gives

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Unknown column 'PrefId' in 'order clause'
```

I also tried with - `ORDER BY FIELD(w.preferenceId, 4, 3, 99, 2, 1, 0)` but that doesn't seem to honour the weighted sort order.

Where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually seem to have two problems here.  First, `PrefId` is an *alias* which you defined in the select clause earlier in the query.  Hibernate seems to be complaining about this, so just use `preferenceId` instead.  Second, `FIELD` is a MySQL extension and is not part of the ANSI standard, nor is it part of the Hibernate query language.  You may however refactor your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(PrefId, 4, 3, 99, 2, 1, 0);
```

to this, using a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE COALESCE(w.preferenceId, 0) WHEN 4  THEN 1
                                     WHEN 3  THEN 2
                                     WHEN 99 THEN 3
                                     WHEN 2  THEN 4
                                     WHEN 1  THEN 5
                                     WHEN 0  THEN 6
                                     ELSE 7  END
```